# What is the impact of overriding SerializationPolicy in GWT and validating all types

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

Quite often during development we see this error.

com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'com.test.TestDTO' was not assignable to 'com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable' and did not have a custom field "serializer.For security purposes, this type will not be serialized".

Can some one please tell me what is security concern here?

What is impact of overriding SerializationPolicy and ignoring validations by by providing empty implementation for validateSerialize and validateDeserialize methods.

Comment: What is your intention? Is it just to avoid the exception or you want to know about overriding SeriazationPolicy?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want to know that will I be introducing any security venerability by overriding security policy and ignoring above exception?